# JQuery masked input plugin does not work on IE7

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, cross-browser

I'm using Jquery Masked input plugin 
http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/

According to the changelog it should support IE7

When when trying to use it on IE7 It's does not work and I'm getting the following error in IE debugger

**Object doesn't support property or method 'mask'**

My code :

```
$("#" + "someid").mask(someformat);
```

The same code work on all other browsers 
including IE8 and above.

Comment: what version of jQuery you are using?

Comment: @john Smith. can you post the HTML too?

Comment: @Jai - Jquery version 1.3.2

Comment: @Arjuncc - the input tag -
<input name="someid" class="someclass" id="someid" type="text" size="30" maxLength="255" value="somevalue"/>

Comment: @john have you tried with latest jQuery 1.9+? 1.3 is quite older one.

Comment: @Jai - I can't update the Jquery version at the moment since all the project I'm working on is based on version 1.3

Comment: I have checked the following code in IE7 mode in IE8, it works fine
http://jsfiddle.net/arjuncc/SRgGE/

Comment: I also tested it , it is working But I need IE7 and not mode IE8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For IE7 try to use version 1.2.2 of masked-input
https://zk-sample-code.googlecode.com/svn-history/r27/trunk/WebContent/samples/sam/inputbox/js/jquery.maskedinput-1.2.2.js

```
$(function () {
   $("[name='in1']").mask("99/99/9999");
   $("[name='in2']").mask("99-99-99");  
});
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/ishubin/aVwpn/

Answer (score 2):

Error in script jquery.maskedinput.js!

now:

```
$.mask = {
    //Predefined character definitions
    definitions: {
        '9': "[0-9]",
        'a': "[A-Za-z]",
        '*': "[A-Za-z0-9]"
    },
    dataName: "rawMaskFn",
    placeholder: '_',
};
```

need:

```
$.mask = {
    //Predefined character definitions
    definitions: {
        '9': "[0-9]",
        'a': "[A-Za-z]",
        '*': "[A-Za-z0-9]"
    },
    dataName: "rawMaskFn",
    placeholder: '_'
};
```

work on IE7!