# jQuery regex inputmask does not work in IE 7

Tags: jquery, regex, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7, jquery-inputmask

I am using the jQuery inputmask from https://github.com/RobinHerbots/jquery.inputmask and have no problem in Firefox, Chrome or IE 8+.

However, when I use the below regex input masks, IE 7 only displays the first character from the data source.  I know the data is present because if I switch document modes from IE 7 standards to IE 8 standards or higher, the data is immediately visible.

Is there any way to get the regex input mask to show all the data in IE 7?

```
$(".alpha").inputmask('Regex', { regex: "[a-zA-Z ]+" }); // Limits entry to letters and space character
$(".name").inputmask('Regex', { regex: "[a-zA-Z-`' ]+" }); // Limits entry to letters, -, `, ' and space character 
$(".alphanumeric").inputmask('Regex', { regex: "[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+" }); // Limits entry to letters, numbers and space character
```

Comment: Are you getting an error in Ie7 when this happens?

Comment: No error, it just displays the first character of data

Comment: Maybe this help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16010469/2097224

Comment: I'm so sorry that you have to support IE7 (maybe it is time to look for a better job???)

Comment: I wish I did not have to support IE 7 but I do

Comment: **[IE7 COUNTDOWN](http://theie7countdown.com/)** ;)

Comment: @aldanux the problem usually comes when you have to deal with some public institutions

Comment: @A.Wolff - I know.. but that is sad

Comment: Not even Microsoft supports IE7 anymore.  This feature was never supposed to work in IE7.  Supporting IE7 is a bad thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears this is related to the IE 7 lookahead bug documented here http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/regex-lookahead-bug  Changing the above regex to this resolved the problem (replaced the + with {n,m})

```
// Due to lookahead bug in IE 7, used {n,m} instead of just +
$(".alpha").inputmask('Regex', { regex: "[a-zA-Z ]{1,50}" }); // Limits entry to letters and space character
$(".name").inputmask('Regex', { regex: "[a-zA-Z-`' ]{1,50}" }); // Limits entry to letters, -, `, ' and space character 
$(".alphanumeric").inputmask('Regex', { regex: "[a-zA-Z0-9 ]{1,50}" }); // Limits entry to letters, numbers and space character
```